Из заданных чисел необходимо найти самое маленькое, и если таких чисел несколько, то выбрать из них самое крайнее(ближе к концу)
Пример ввода: 3 4 2 5 10 2 3 1 1 45
Вывод: 9
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
for k in range(len(a)):
  if a[k] ==  min(a):
       x = str ((a.index(a[k+1])))       
       print(max(x))


В целом код вообще непонятно что делает. Код должен быть понятен хотя бы вам. Я что-то не уверен, что вы его сможете объяснить. Например, что такое в последних двух строках происходит? )

Давайте включим логику. Судя по примеру, нужно найти индекс последнего из минимальных значений, а не само значение.
Значит, если мы идем вправо, и очередное число не больше текущего минимума - запоминаем его индекс
imin = 0
for k in range(len(a)):
    if a[k] <=  a[imin]:
        imin = k
print(imin)

